# Alternating series error estimatation theorem for $\sum_1^{\infty} (-1)^{n+3}\frac{n}{n^2+8}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_1^{\infty} (-1)^{n+3}\frac{n}{n^2+8}$$

Here is my question: Using the alternating series error estimation theorem, what is the smallest number of terms needed to estimate the entire sum with an error of magnitude less than $10^{-6}$?

So from what I know about the alternating series error estimation theorem, it's when you have to list out the terms and adding up a certain number of terms makes the error of the estimation the next term that was left out of the group of terms.

So I wrote out the first few terms, is that how you approach this problem? Am I supposed to find the term with the 0.000001 place?

Here are the first few terms:

0.11 - 0.166 + 0.176 - 0.16 + 0.151

So far I do not see any term to that place. Is there some other way to do this problem?

Comment: I suppose that you did not finish your last sentence.

Comment: oh wait let me fix that thanks

Comment: So your problem is that none of the **five** first terms is less than 10^{-6}? Sorry but (1) does this really come as a surprise? and (2) sure you have no idea how to overcome this obstacle?

Comment: @Did well um ya I just started learning about this theorem, so (1)ya it comes as a surprise and (2)my only idea is to keep listing out terms. Is that how it goes?

Comment: Imagine that the first suitable term is at n = 10^6... Still think this is how it goes? And if you were asked for some rest less than 10^{-12}...

Comment: Try to make the statement more general, may be. What is $n$ such that $???$ ? From there, you could conclude.

Comment: @Did well how else do I do this problem? Isn't the goal to find the first term to be in the form of 0.000000?

Comment: Hint: How to solve the *exact same question* for the series $$\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\quad ?$$

Comment: @Did let me try that

Comment: The question should be interpreted as:
Find the first $N$ such that
$$\varepsilon_N \stackrel{def}{=}\left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+3}\frac{n}{n^2+8} - \sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n+3}\frac{n}{n^2+8}\right| < 10^{-6}$$

The *alternating series error estimation theorem* tells you if
the underlying series is decreasing, the error $\varepsilon_N$ is bounded from above by the first term you skip. i.e

$$\varepsilon_N = \left| \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty (-1)^{n+3}\frac{n}{n^2+8} \right|
\le \frac{(N+1)}{(N+1)^2+8}\tag{*1}$$
Your question becomes: "What is the first $N$ such that RHS$(*1) < 10^{-6}$"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Calabrese criteria (see the references) to approximate the sum of alternating series:

References:

http://ecademy.agnesscott.edu/~lriddle/apcalculus/approxSeries.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is horribly wrong proposition but that was the case in 1955 at least in some textbooks.

> Using the alternating series error estimation theorem, what is the smallest number of terms

It cannot provide smallest number in all cases! Only some number where error is at least as specified but in reality error can be smaller.

$$0.0000005\le\frac{(N+1)}{(N+1)^2+8}$$

gives $$N \le -0.9999954999657348$$ and $$ 2000000.9999954998\le N$$

So the answer is 2 million terms, now we need to verify there is no smaller value, like 1 million (which is 2 times less, **that is how** Calabrese criteria error bond works).

Well, you can check this with Wolfram Mathematica first.

The sum of the series can be found in symbolic form: $$\frac{1}{4} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(i \sqrt{2}+1\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(i \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(1-i \sqrt{2}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}-i \sqrt{2}\right)\right)$$

where $$\psi ^{(0)}$$ is polygamma function.

We can see that it is actually 1 million terms, not 2 million.

+1 to the guy above who gave the citation.